# Why is the same value on IDENTITY column being returned to two inserters?

Tags: sql-server

My program is inserting into a table like this...

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[MYTABLE] (
    ID [INT] IDENTITY (1,1),
    DATE_TIME [DATETIME],
    NOTES [VARCHAR] (100))
```

using the following code...

```
database_connection = New ADODB.Connection
' ...code to connect...
database_connection.IsolationLevel = ADODB.IsolationLevelEnum.adXactSerializable
database_connection.BeginTrans
command_string = "INSERT INTO [MySchema].[dbo].[MyTable] (NOTES) VALUES ('sometext')"
database_connection.Execute(command_string)
command_string = "SELECT MAX([id]) as max_id FROM [MySchema].[dbo].[MyTable]"
Dim record_set As ADODB.Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
record_set.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
record_set.Open(command_string, database_connection, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, , ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)
record_set.MoveLast
new_id = CInt(record_set.Fields("id").Value)
database_connection.CommitTrans
```

Occasionally this code is executed by two different programs simultaneously (close enough in time that the `date_time` values are identical), and although there are two rows visible in `MyTable`, both programs are running with the same `new_id`.

Although I appreciate I should probably be using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` here (and I'll try it in a minute), I was under the impression that the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction would prevent this from happening. Does anyone know why this duplication is occurring, and if `SCOPE_INDENTITY` will fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way would be opening the recordset with following command, without previous execute

```
INSERT INTO [MySchema].[dbo].[MyTable] (NOTES) 
OUTPUT inserted.id
VALUES ('sometext')
```

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY, but in the same query as INSERT.
When 2 clients insert data in a same table at same time -> the second query will return Max(id) of 2nd inserted value.

```
INSERT INTO [MySchema].[dbo].[MyTable] (NOTES) VALUES ('sometext')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```